# Go to app button-where to fill in the URL

Tags: facebook

Maybe a silly question, but where do I fill in this URL?

I have been looking and looking and testing for two days now! Still I have not found the answer.

Like for example `http://www.facebook.com/Sendible?ref=ts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a setting you can change, the link will automatically go to your app depending on what type of app you've defined in your app settings (i.e canvas - link will go to your canvas page, 'website' - link will go to your site, iOS app - link will go to iTunes store)